# C++: Reference to "out of scope" object

Tags: c++, reference

There is one thing I never understood about references and I hope that one might help me. For all I know, a reference cannot be null. But what happens if you have a function foo() returning a reference to an stack object:

```
Object & foo(){
    Object o;
    return o;
}

Object & ref = foo();
```

Theoretical ref would refer to an non existing object since o runs out of scope as soon as the function returns. Whats happening here?

Comment: A null pointer is not the same thing as an invalid pointer!

Comment: To clarify - nothing prevents a reference from being `null`. You just can't take a reference to `null` directly.

Comment: Even in practice, `ref` would refer to a non-existing object, as would the phrase "the present king of France".

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens when C++ reference leaves it's scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097593/what-happens-when-c-reference-leaves-its-scope)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This causes undefined behaviour. Don't do it.

Implementation-wise, realistically, the reference would point into the stack where the stackframe for the call to `foo` used to be. That memory will in many cases still make sense, so the error is often not immediately apparent. Therefore, you should *take care* never to make a dangling reference like that.

Answer (score 1):

nothing before you use the returned reference - then you'll be reading/writing over your stack

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour in this context is undefined - this isn't particularly odd in c++. This is essentially identical to the situation where you have a pointer set to a local variable which has gone out of scope. C++ requires YOU control handle references and the lifetime of referenced objects.